# touch pad mouse is scrolling the browser page

Tags: windows-xp, browser, touchpad, scrolling

I have an NEC Versa L1100.  I'm running Windows XP SP3.

When I disconnect my USB mouse, and use the laptop's touchpad, I find when I move the mouse cursor around the browser window, the page will scroll as if I am moving the scroll wheel on a mouse.  It happens intermittently.  I don't have any buttons pressed down as it happens.

What can cause this?

How can it be fixed?

Thanks,

Steve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably the scrollbar at the right of the touchpad guy...just saying.  I hate to point at the obvious, but....

Comment: IS there a scrollbar at the right of the touchpad?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am using the centre of the touchpad, not the right hand side.

Comment: Actually, I think you might be right.

Comment: Is there a way to turn the scrollbar off?

Comment: that depends on the driver...check mouse options or any application that relates to the mouse(synaptic is a common driver software)